# Erro de log.Append

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma planilha excel com campos referentes a datas, entretanto, caso eu não preencha esses campos, deverei exibir log de mensagem para esse usuário, porém se deixo em branco, não é mostrado o log.

Coloquei o breakpoint para debugar, porém ao compilar o código ele não passa nessa parte de forma alguma.

```
Dados = DadosExcel(Excel);

                    Dados.Columns.Add("indice", typeof(int));
                    // Gambiarra, porém funciona, pegando os valores(indice da linha)
                    int i = 1;

                    foreach (DataRow linha in Dados.Rows)
                    {
                        linha["indice"] = i;
                        i++;
                    }
private void setProcInter(Processo processo, Interessado interessado, DataRow linha, int i)
    {

        i = 4;
        i++;

        try
        {
            if (processo == null)
                processo = new Processo();

            if (!linha.ItemArray[17].ToString().Equals(""))
                processoInteressado.CodigoSep = decimal.Parse(linha.ItemArray[17].ToString());
            else
                processoInteressado.CodigoSep = null;
            try
            {
                DateTime DataSep = DateTime.Parse(linha.ItemArray[18].ToString());
                processoInteressado.DataSep = DataSep;
            }
            catch
            {
                logErro.Append("A célula S" + (linha["indice"]) + " deve estar preenchida com uma data. <br>");
                arquivoInvalidado = true;
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime DataEntradaSefaz = DateTime.Parse(linha.ItemArray[19].ToString());
                processoInteressado.DataEntradaSefaz = DataEntradaSefaz;
            }
            catch
            {
                logErro.Append("A célula T" + (linha["indice"]) + " deve estar preenchida com uma data. <br>");
                arquivoInvalidado = true;
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime DataRequisicaoPgto = DateTime.Parse(linha.ItemArray[0].ToString());
                processoInteressado.DataDoValorBruto = DataRequisicaoPgto;
            }
            catch
            {
                logErro.Append("A célula A" + (linha["indice"]) + " deve estar preenchida com uma data. <br>");
                arquivoInvalidado = true;
            }
            processoInteressado.Interessado = interessado;

        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            arquivoInvalidado = true;
            logErro.Append(erro.Message + "<br>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você precisa detalhar bem sua pergunta, exemplo, você diz: ..."porém ao compilar o código ele não passa nessa parte de forma alguma"... o que você quer dizer com esse "nessa parte", em qual dessas linhas ocorre erro? Qual é a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte forma: if (linha.ItemArray[19].ToString().Equals(""))
                    {
                        log.Append("A célula T linha " + (linha["indice"]) + " deve ser preenchida. <br>");
                        arquivoInvalidado = true;
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
 if (linha.ItemArray[19].ToString().Equals("")) 

{


log.Append("A célula T linha " + (linha["indice"]) + " deve ser preenchida<br>");



arquivoInvalidado = true; 



 }
```